# Cursor theme won't change in Ubuntu 14.04 for me

Tags: 14.04, cursor, cursor-theme

I can't figure out how to change this stupid black cursor into the theme I've downloaded. It shows up in Ubuntu Tweak, but selecting it does absolutely nothing. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The following method works for me !

In the following method, I use the cursor theme `OpenZone_Black` as an example.

1. Extract you downloaded theme to `～/.icons` or  `/usr/share/icons/` (I choose `/usr/share/icons/` in the example)

   ```
   sudo tar -xv -f ~/Downloads/OpenZone/OpenZone_Black-1.2.3.tar.xz -C /usr/share/icons/
   ```
2. Copy the `cursor.theme` file under the system cursor theme folder(like `DMZ-White`) to your downloaded theme folder.

   ```
     sudo cp -a /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme /usr/share/icons/OpenZone_Black/
   ```

   3. open your copied `cursor.theme`, and change the line to

      ```
      [Icon Theme] Inherits=OpenZone_Black
      ```
   4. Execute the following command in the same terminal at a time:

      1. record your downloaded theme

         ```
              CURSOR=OpenZone_Black
         ```
      2. add to `alternative x-cursor-theme`:

         ```
              sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/$CURSOR/cursor.theme 20
         ```
      3. change the cursor theme

         ```
             sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
         ```

         now select the cursor theme.